# How do I fix(make) apps windows to be opened at desired place of the desktop?

Tags: 14.04, .desktop

For example I want SMPlayer window to be always opened in the middle of the desktop because when I place it in the middle every time that I launch it goes up left to the top with time so I have to drag it back and I kinda dislike repeating it again and again.

So how do I make an opened app window to be placed where I want it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the script below with the arguments:

```
<application> <x> <y>
```

The window of the application will be placed at x, y on your screen.

#### How to set up

The script uses both `wmctrl` and `xdotool`:

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

Then:

1. The most elegant way is to Copy the script into an empty file and save it in `~/bin` (you might have to create the directory) as `place_window` (no extension)
2. Make the script executable (!)
3. If you just created `~/bin`, either log out / in or run the command:

   ```
   source ~/.profile
   ```
4. Test run it with the command (e.g):

   ```
   place_window gedit 100 100
   ```

   A gedit window should appear at x = 100, y = 100 on your screen.

If all works fine, you can either put the command under a shortcut combination (choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts"), or at it as a quicklist -shortcut to an application launcher.

#### The script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import getpass
import time
import sys

app = sys.argv[1]
user = getpass.getuser()
get = lambda x: subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", x]).decode("utf-8")
ws1 = get("wmctrl -lp"); t = 0
subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", app])

while t < 30:      
    ws2 = [w.split()[0:3] for w in get("wmctrl -lp").splitlines() if not w in ws1]
    procs = [[(p, w[0]) for p in get("ps -u "+user).splitlines() \
              if app[:14] in p and w[2] in p] for w in ws2]
    if len(procs) > 0:
        w_id = procs[0][0][1]   
        cmd1 = "wmctrl -ir "+w_id+" -b remove,maximized_vert remove,maximized_horz"
        cmd2 = "xdotool windowmove "+w_id+" "+sys.argv[2]+" "+sys.argv[3]
        for cmd in [cmd1, cmd2]:
            subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd])
        break
    time.sleep(0.5)
    t = t+1
```

#### How it works

The scripts runs the command to start the application, waits for the corresponding window to appear (waiting for the pid to produce a new window) and positions it to the coordinates you define.

```
place_window gedit 50 150
```

[image]

```
place_window gedit 150 50
```

[image]

#### Setting the command as a quicklist item

The most elegant would be to add it as a keyboard shortcut, or, alternatively, as a quicklist item:

[image]

In that case, the command to use in the `Exec=` line would be e.g.:

```
Exec=/bin/bash -c "place_window gedit 600 600"
```

Comment: Either root or not running `place_window gedit 100 100` I get `bash: /home/admin/bin/place_window: Permission denied` or `place_window: command not found`

Comment: @JoKeR You most probably forgot to make it executable or didn't log out/in after you created the directory `~/bin`.  `admin` is your username right? In any case it should work with: `python3 /path/to/place_window gedit 100 100`

Comment: Put `./` before name of the script to launch it in folder.

Comment: @AndreyRybak why would you do that? If you put in in $PATH and make it executable, the command is simply <script> <applications> <x> <y>.

Comment: @AndreyRybak Ah, sorry Your comment was related to JoKeR's comment :)

Comment: Thank you @JacobVlijm, indeed I forgot to make it exec :) It works now.

Comment: Perfect :) I made a small change to make sure the called window is not maximized (then the positioning would not work).

Comment: Yet I do need just a hint where exactly do I input `Exec=/bin/bash -c "place_window gedit 600 600"` because I'm a bit lost or doing smth wrong, I want to add it as a quicklist item.

Comment: I figured it out I just edited `smplayer.desktop` to make it work. Thanks for helping.