# Advanced window placement

Tags: unity, compiz, window-management, window-placement

**TLDR** I'm looking for a ubuntu replacement of [windowpad](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/19990-windowpad-window-moving-tool/)

I know window placement can be defined with `Ctrl`-`Alt`-`Numpad#` and `Ctrl`-`Super`-`arrow` But those are not sufficent. I do have *CompizConfig* > *Cycle Through Multiple Sizes*

But I want to assign a hotkey to make a window stick to the left, full height, 1/3rd width. The same for the right. and one for the middle. I'm used to using Windowpad (on windows) which allows me to define pretty much anything. And I'm so used to it.

Any way to tweak this?

Clarify Edit.
This is not about opening windows but about the current active windows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fix(make) apps windows to be opened at desired place of the desktop?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/608497/how-do-i-fixmake-apps-windows-to-be-opened-at-desired-place-of-the-desktop)

Comment: @JoKeR thanks for the reply but it's not about new (opening) windows. I want to manipulate the active window.

Comment: did you check this one http://askubuntu.com/questions/18243/moving-windows-from-the-keyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [`xdotool`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/xdotool.1.html) or [`wmctrl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/wmctrl.1.html). These are tools that let you script various interactions with the GUI. Both can be installed from the repositories, you can use whichever one you prefer:

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl xdotool
```

My display is 1920 x 1080, so 1/3rd width would be 640. To place the active window at the left side of the screen, full height and 1/3rd width, I would run:

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,0,0,640,1080
```

The format is explained in `man wmctrl`:

```
-r <WIN>
     Specify a target window for an action.
-e <MVARG>
     Resize and move a window that has been specified with a -r action 
     according to the  <MVARG> argument.

 [...]

<MVARG>
     A move and resize argument has the format 'g,x,y,w,h'.  All five components  are  integers.
     The  first  value, g, is the gravity of the window, with 0 being the
     most common value (the default value for the window). [...]
     The four remaining values are a standard geometry specification: x,y 
     is the position of the top  left  corner  of  the  window, and w,h
     is the width and height of the window [...].

<WIN>
     This  argument  specifies a window that is the target of an action. [...]
     The  window name string :ACTIVE: may be used to instruct wmctrl to 
     use the currently active window for the action.
```

You could also make it more dynamic by detecting the width automatically. This command prints the width of your display:

```
$ xrandr | grep -Po 'current\s*\K\d+'
1920
```

You could, therefore, integrate it into `wmctrl` like this:

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,0,0,$(($(xrandr | grep -Po 'current\s*\K\d+')/3)),1080
```

Now, all you have to do is assign that command to a keyboard shortcut from the Unity Settings and you're all set.

Comment: I like your answers: "Sounds like ..." +1 =)

Comment: That seems to work. I do have a laptop which sometimes has a 2nd screen and sometimes not. Looks like I'll have to hit the docs.

Comment: @janw the output of `xrandr` should always give the right value. I've written a script that snaps to the left or right side of the screen and works with single or dual monitor setups. That might give you an idea of what is possible. I've posted it in my answer here: [How can I start up an application with a pre-defined window size and position?](http://askubuntu.com/a/613990)

Comment: Thanks. But after a bit more research for now I'm concluding that I don't have enough *bash* and *regex* skills to execute it, I do have the structure thought out and noted down. I'll check it again in a few months.

Comment: @janw do what you can and post a new question. That's how you learn! :)

Comment: I'll try a basic tut or 2 and then I'll get back. I'm not afraid to [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/users/933065/janw) ;)

Comment: Sorry to be a thread necro. But the X & Y coordinates 0 0 aren't really working :( http://i.imgur.com/y2tbXVd.png any idea?

Comment: I gueas  it has to do with the WA shown in `wmctrl -d` gonna search if I can lower that...

Comment: @janw yes, it looks like Unity is reserving a lot of space so `0,0` doesn't actually correspond to the top left. I have never used Unity (and don't intend to) so I can't really help there.

Comment: I can't find examples of people having the same problem. Mint with Cinamon doesn't have this problem.

Comment: @janw it wouldn't, it looks like a unity thing. Feel free to unaccept my answer but you're probably more likely to find a solution if you post a new question, linking to this one and explain the specific issue.

Comment: I see no reason to unaccept. I've not settled on a Linux flavour. This is a crucial feature for me. So big enough to switch. Still I'll think I'll post a question.